# What is resonance in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, resonance

Could anyone please explain what resonance in particle physics is and what resonance peaks are? 
Also how resonance relates to certain results?
the certain results are the decay of a particle which leads to a  positron energy, electron energy and an angle. the data i found was the reconstructed mass. how would i find the resonance peak of the reconstructed mass?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of "resonance" in a simpler system (Like a driven mass on a spring, driven pendulum or something similar)? How much do you know about quantum mechanics in the first place; do you recognize the parts of the mathematical foundation of QM that are similar to the math for driven oscillators?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188015/what-is-the-essential-difference-between-a-resonance-and-a-particle?rq=1

Comment: Could you please specify the level of answers you are looking for?

Comment: A resonance is an increase in the cross section of a process in some energy range due to the existence of an (unstable) state at the resonance energy (frequency). If you think about the vacuum as a bell that can be made to ring, a resonance would be one of the discrete tones on which the vacuum can ring.

Comment: What are these "certain results" you mention in your second sentence?

Comment: the certain results are the decay of a particle which leads to a  positron energy, electron energy and an angle. the data i found was the reconstructed mass. how would i find the resonance peak of the reconstructed mass?

Comment: @edelor69, does [this website](http://www.desy.de/~ameyer/hq/node20.html) help?

Comment: @CuriousOne Please convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resonance (in particle physics) is the peak located around a certain energy found in functions that quantify the given rate at which scattered particles can be detected at a given angle (in [scattering experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering)). The peaks are associated with subatomic particles and their [excitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excited_state) (i.e., any quantum state of these particles that is higher than ground state).

You can learn more about resonances in the context of particle physics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(particle_physics)). You can learn about resonances in simpler systems (like those mentioned by dmckee) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance). Hope this helps!