# What exactly are resonances in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, definition, resonance, quasiparticles

I am very confused about this, are they an excited state of a particle where an electron is excited to an upper energy level, which seems less likely to be the case since the resonant states of particles have different names; or are they the constructive interferences of the wave functions of two different particles, which again doesn't seem likely since as far as I know, one wave function is used to describe a system of particles instead of different wave functions.

I am aware of the [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270755/), but the answer there doesn't satisfy me

Comment: maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/414081/

Comment: So what is unsatisfactory? Replace "electron" with "quark", in your question, and: that's a resonance in the baryon sector.

Comment: While I was looking for sources to answer this very deep question, I stumbled upon this article https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-the-physics-of-resonance-shapes-reality-20220126/ that says everything I wanted to say, so I decided to write a comment instead. I think it answers your question beautifully. If not, let me know and I will try to fill the gaps with a proper answer

Comment: @Prallax so as far as i've understood, every particle is a resonance of the fields defined by the quantum field theory, and with "resonance" usually the very short lived 'particles' a.k.a resonances of the fields are refered, right?

Comment: yes, it's a good way to phrase it

Comment: @Prallax thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be because you are confusing an *excited state* with a *resonance*. I think it was Anthony Zee who described a resonance (in the context of a scattering experiment) as a fleeting hand-hold between *two* particles as they pass closely by one another.

I like to think of it as if the particles were square dancers who approach, join hands, circle once or twice (and maybe kiss), then let go, and go their separate ways. While holding hands they behave as a composite object, and if they kiss then both of them will be something different when they let go (their heart rates will be changed, one of them will have lipstick marks on him, etc.).

This is a crude analogy and I invite the experts here to weigh in.

Comment: then why do resonances have different names than the two particles? and why do they decay to different particles?

Comment: @gluon, will edit. -NN