# What is the difference between a bound state and a resonance state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

A bound state is: given a potential vanishing at infinity, negative-energy states must be bound.

How can I distinguish between a bound state and a resonance state in particles physics?

Comment: IsaacNewton, I edited your question. You may revert the edit if you're unhappy with it.

Comment: also see the answers here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188015/what-is-the-essential-difference-between-a-resonance-and-a-particle